# Passing a hex color to an ASP.NET page using ULR Parameter

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am trying to allow a user to specify a background color for my asp.net website.  So I want to pass the page color into my url like:

```
UserDetails.aspx?Color=#FFFFFF
```

However as soon as I include the # character I can't seem to be able to get the correct value for the parameter Color using:

```
color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Request.Params["Color"]);
```

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pound character (#) is used in URLs to indicate where a fragment identifier (bookmarks/anchors in HTML) begins. You'll probably want to URL encode it as %23.

Or, as Andrew noted in a comment, you could have the user pass the parameter without the pound sign and add it in later.

Comment: or skip the url encoding and just have them pass through the hex code without the #.  Then add the # sign back in in your code

Answer (score 4):

```
UserDetails.aspx?Color=FFFFFF

string colString = Request["Color"];
Color col = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(String.Format("#{0}", colString));
```

Answer (score 0):

or you coould just omit the hash and write like this

color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + Request.Params["Color"]);

ive not tested the above, but find no reason for it not to work, you could decalre this above maybe too

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying the querystring client side, I would make use of the JavaScript [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) method to encode all of your data.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, be aware of the [HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx). All query string parameters should be URL encoded before being passed via URL. "URL encoding converts characters that are not allowed in a URL into character-entity equivalents." eg.

```
string colour = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("#FFFFFF");
string url = "UserDetails.aspx?Color=" + colour;
```